# web3 with NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, ethereum, web3js, nativescript-plugin

How can I use the web3.js library (for Ethereum development) in NativeScript?

I tried:

- install web3 via `npm install web3@0.20.7 --save`
- install web3 through plugin manager in sidekick
- even tried `const Web3
  =require('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js');`
- also tried `const Web3 = require("./web3.min.js");` with the web3.min.js file in the folder, but then `console.log(Web3)` just prints an empty array.

Also, I added the NativeScript plugin nativescript-nodeify

In the first three cases, I get an exception saying (amongst others) "Calling js method onCreate failed"

Note: I explicitly do not want to go via a back end to handle the interaction with Ethereum

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this one?  I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: you can use web3 inside a webview, use @nota/nativescript-webview-ext so that you can communicate back and forth between webview and your nativescript code. (I have used it like this and is has worked well for me)

Comment: do you mean you hosted part of the code somewhere and used it in NS app via webview

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to make web3js work with NativeScript indeed. It looks like it is impossible, as web3 will use the browser to communicate with metamask for example.

Nervetheless, there may be a solution, using eth.js  :

```
// in your root project directory
// NOT with nativescript sidekick !
npm install --save ethjs
tns plugin add nativescript-nodeify

// then, in your code
require("nativescript-nodeify");
const Eth = require('ethjs');
```

Then, you can interact with ethereum blockchain.

EDIT: The TNS plugin name is nativescript-nodeify

Comment: Are you able to share the sample how you managed to get ethjs to work with nativescript?